# The probability distribution of "derivative" of a random variable

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

*Let me set the stage;*

Consider a stochastic PDE, which has to following form

$$\partial_t h(x,t) = H(x,t) + \chi(x,t),$$
where $H$ is a deterministic function, and $\chi(x,t)$ is a random variable.

In my case, the approximate solution of to this sPDE is known (via experimental and numerical simulations):

$$h(x,t) \approx G(x,t) + \epsilon(x,t),$$
where $\epsilon$ is a stochastic variable.

Of course, the solution of $h$ is not differentiable in the usual sense, but if the underlying distribution of $\epsilon$ is a symmetric distribution, such as a Gaussian one, if you observe $\partial_t h$ for long enough times, the deviations of $h$ from $G$ will be cancel out, so that you can experimentally or numerically determine $G$ quite accurately.

However, this requires us to know the *distribution of the changes in the values $\epsilon$*.

In this sense, this is "taking the derivative of" $\epsilon$.

A short analysis revealed me that, if the underlying probability distribution of $\epsilon$ is $g$ (let just assume that $\epsilon$ is a function of only t for the sake of the argument), then

the probability that $z-w$ change to occur is $g(z)g(w)$, because if the value of $\epsilon$ at the time $t$ is $z$, then at $t + dt$, the probability that $\epsilon (t+dt) = w$ is $g(w)$; therefore, considering that the probability that $\epsilon(t) = z$ in the first place is $g(z)$, so the probability that (Attention: abuse of notation) $d \epsilon = z-w$ is $g(w)g(z)$ (of course, this need some proper normalisation, but it is irrelevant to what I want to ask in here).

For example, if my analysis is correct, the "derivative" of a Gaussian random variable is still a Gaussian one.

---

**Question:**

Considering how "elementary" this idea made me wonder, is there a theory that captures the calculus on random variable in this sort ? I would also like to integrate random variables (though I haven't thought what that would mean physically or intuitively). I'm looking for references/papers dealing with this kind of theory; not just "taking derivative" of a random variable in a random sense, I need exactly above way of thinking in the theory.

I mean, I'm aware of the existence of Ito calculus, and Malliavin calculus, but whenever I tried to learn what is all about, or what is the underlying idea (such as what does taking derivative physically means in those theories) people would start to throw at me terminology that I'm not familiar. Don't get me wrong, I'm a also mathematics student, but in mathematics, doing theory without giving any motivation or the basic idea is so common, and I hate in such a way that I even don't read math books anymore.

Comment: Here is my advice: learn how to use Itô calculus. Learn Itô’s lemma for a basic process (like Brownian motion) and gradually study its generalizations while filling in the details of all the terminology (they are just *words* and each one has a specific meaning usually standardized by most authors—learn them!). The motivation of such a large subject as stochastic calculus is not something one can really get a grasp of prior to digging into the subject itself and its admittedly daunting terminology.

Comment: My comment is in the spirit of this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/19259 about motivating open sets in topology, for some context.

Comment: @NapD.Lover I *can* learn Ito calculus, no problem; but I have to first make sure that, for example, the derivate operation in that theory captures the above feature of  a random variable; I mean, I can also create Ito calculus v2. by making an arbitrary definition for derivative for stochastic variable, and that would not capture the above physical property. Therefore, I have to ** first** know that, for example, that aking derivative in that theory physical mean; if I can understand what I'm doing in practice, and get an intuitive feeling, the rest not a problem.

Comment: @NapD.Lover However, as you can have already guess, I don't know what does Ito calculus do, what does "taking derivative" physical means in Ito Calculus; and that is the question, in a sense, is there is a theory that captures the above physical property of a random variable (for example Ito, does that captures it) ? if there is, what are good references for that ?

Comment: Here is a brief foray into Itô calculus: the SDE in differential notation $dX_t=\mu dt+\sigma dB_t$ is actually short hand for the integral equation $X_t-X_s =\int_s^t \mu dw + \int_s^t \sigma dB_w$ where the first integral is the Lebesgue integral and the second is an Itô integral and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. If $u(t,x)$ is $C^{1,2}$ then by Itô’s formula we can compute the SDE for $Y_t:=u(t, X_t)$ as $dY_t=(u_t+\mu u_x + \frac 12 \sigma^2 u_{xx})dt+\sigma u_x dB_t$ where subscripts of $u$ are partial derivatives.

Comment: So Itô’s formula is like the stochastic chain rule. But Brownian motion has a lot of wild properties. It has continuous sample paths but is nowhere differentiable with respect to $t$ almost surely. Its *total variation* is infinite but its *quadratic variation* is given by $[B]_t=t$, which is used in Itô’s formula above but I went ahead with simplifications so as to not mention it. Since $B_t$ is not differentiable with respect to time, neither is the process $X_t$ above and the only reason $Y_t=u(t, X_t)$ is differentiable with respect to time is that we assumed $u$ was smooth enough.

Comment: @NapD.Lover You gave a perfect example of what I hate about the way how mathematics is taught. I don't need formulas, or theorems, I can learn them by myself. What I need is what does all those theorems actually means; for example, why did people define the derivative or integral of a in this way ? or what does taking derivative in this fashion physically mean ? I can also define the derivative of any stochastic varialbe as jest $1$, and that wouldn't be a usefull definition, as long as I don't give you a string argument why the derivative of any stochastic variable should be one!

Comment: (I cannot answer your specific questions on the idea you want to capture because I cannot parse it. For one what is the random variable $\chi(x,t)$? If we are to be rigorous, one perspective is that a stochastic process is a map $X: [0,\infty)\times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\Omega$ is the sample space, so that for each fixed outcome $\omega$ the path $X_t(\omega):=X(t, \omega)$ is a single sample path over time of the process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$. Your RV takes an additional spatial variable, and if it was for example $\chi(x,t)=xB_t$ then already it is not differentiable in $t$.)

Comment: Well, sorry! Good luck...

Comment: My motivation for learning the Ito calculus was options pricing, as in John Hull's Options, Futures, and Other Derivatives. If you care about financial SDEs, that might be a place to look for motivation. Or if not that, what SDEs do you care about? Expositions of those applications may also lead towards the terminology that you haven't been motivated to learn yet.

Comment: @MattF. I have enough motivation to learn any theory that make "calculus" with stochastic variable; the problem is, theory has to have a physical meaning, (in particular, the derivative should mean what I outlined above); for example, as I gave in the above comments, is you define the derivative of any stochastic variable as just $1$, this definition do not have any physical meaning; similarly, you can do calculus on stochastic variable with any arbitrary definition. What I need a mathematical theory with a **physically** plausible definitions.